# Why does timedelta function return 0 seconds when datetimes are perfect number of days apart?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timedelta

`end_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
start_time = end_time - datetime.timedelta(days=14)`

`(end_time - start_time).seconds = 0
(end_time - start_time).days = 14`

The curious part is if I add/subtract a second from the time delta, I get back the expect response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time difference is 14 days and 0 seconds.

```
diff = end_time - start_time
diff
```

gives:

```
datetime.timedelta(14)
```

One second:

```
s1 = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
```

Now:

```
diff - s1
```

gives:

```
datetime.timedelta(13, 86399)
```

that is 13 days and 86399 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. I had assumed (incorrectly) that calling seconds would give me the TOTAL timedelta in seconds.

Answer (score 5):

If you need your difference in seconds then call timedelta's total_seconds()

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds

Comment: Thanks, this helped me in my situation :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are doing, but if you use

```
start_time = end_time - datetime.timedelta(days=14, seconds=20)
```

and type

```
(end_time - start_time).seconds
```

you will get 20 as your answer 
Also to clarify why it is returning 0, timedelta object is returned if you use

```
(end_time - start_time)
```

where seconds attribute will be 0.

You cannot use

```
(end_time - start_time).seconds = 20
```

as it is a readonly attribute.
If you wanted to get the total number of seconds, you could have used

```
(end_time - start_time).total_seconds()
```

Comment: ah, thanks. For some reason I had assumed (clearly incorrectly) that it was the TOTAL timedelta in seconds.

Comment: @YannickDawant you are welcome, also whichever answer that helped you out, mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark next to the answer